# Adding time values to jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using

```
$("#nav_mobileInlineSolution ul").animate({ height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle" });
```

But want to specify the time the animation should last - how can I add that in whilst keeping the animation working as it is?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it as second parameter:

```
$("#nav_mobileInlineSolution ul").animate({ height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle" }, 1000);
```

That is the duration in msec, so it would last for 1 second here.

See also http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

In most of the signatures [shown in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), duration is the second argument:

```
$("#nav_mobileInlineSolution ul").animate(
    { height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle" },
    durationGoesHere
);
```

The above would be the [first documented signature](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete).